# Offline RPM package install, with Windows

Tags: linux, centos, yum, rpm, packages

I need to install packages with `yum` on a CentOS machine I have. This CentOS server is not connected to the Internet because of my organization policy, but I do have a Windows server that is connected to the Internet.

How can I use something similar to `yumdownloader` on Windows to transfer it back to the CentOS machine?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I would go through 2 different ways depending on the number of packages needed:

1. For small number of packages with no complex dependencies, I would merely download the packages from repositories using a browser (http://mirror.centos.org/centos/)
2. If many packages are needed, I would setup a centos VM in the Windows host (using VMware, VirtualBox or Hyper-V), using yumdownloader or yum update with --downloadonly flag.

Comment: Thank you! Option #2 is just what I should have thought of.